# Go agouti testing fill textarea with PhantomJS perfomance issue

Tags: testing, go, phantomjs, agouti

I am using agouti with gomega and ginkgo in Go to test an upload form of our application consisting of an textarea which we fill.

This Code works fine for 1500 rows:

```
upload_externalData := page.Find("#upload_externalData")
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
f, err := os.Open("./files/external.log")
io.Copy(buf, f)
externalData := string(buf.Bytes())
Expect(upload_externalData.Fill(string(externalData))).Should(Succeed())
```

When increasing the imported data to the normal 25000 rows, PhantomJS blocks one CPU Core at 100% and nothing else happens.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: There is an arbitrary limitation in PhantomJS that only enables you to upload for at most 30 seconds. Does your upload exceed this?

Comment: No it doesn't. The main problem was entering large amount of text into the textarea, which is why we replaced that step by uploading a file. Which is now working fine. Not a solution - but a workaround. Thnx anyways for giving a thougt.